# VIM with Google Docs?

Tags: vim, google-docs

I finally got around to teaching myself VIM and am really liking it. I was wondering if anyone here knew of a way to set up my Google Docs to support the VIM commands?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Best I can find is [GoogleCL](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/w/list) which will let you edit a Google Doc from the command line.

```
google docs edit --title "My Document" --editor vim
```

Unfortunately I got a 503 error when I attempted to use this tool on a new file.  Editing an existing doc worked.

Comment: Nice, but how to install `GoogleCL` i am using linux.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. See the announcement at the top of the page:

"8 June 2015: GoogleCL is currently broken due to the OAuth1 turndown, and likely to remain so. Thanks for your support over the years, and apologies for the lack of prior notice."